# Jpql query across tables

Tags: jpa, orm, jpql

Let'say i have the following tables:

```
Table A: id b-id
Table B: id property
```

Can I filter elements of table A like the following in JPQL language?

SELECT a FROM A a JOIN a.b-id targetId WHERE targetId.property = : someValue

I'd like to get table A's elements in which the referenced B element has property = someValue

And if I introduce a third table

```
Table A: id b-id
Table B: id c-id
Table C: id property
```

How can I get A's elements where c.property=someValue ?

I'm starting to get a sense of the power of ORM but some concepts are still vague to me.
Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPQL queries operate to entities, not to database tables. I assume names of entities and persistent attributes match to the names of tables and database columns given in question.

Because all relations in question are single valued, one-to-one or many-to-one (each `A` is connected only to one `B` (or possibly not to any), each `B` is connected to one `C`), specifying joins in query is not needed at all.

SELECT a FROM A a WHERE a.b.c.property = someValue

There is no need to worry about null values in path, because as said in JPA 2.0 specification:

```
Path expression navigability is composed using “inner join” semantics. 
That is, if the value of a non-terminal field in the path expression is null, 
the path is considered to have no value, and does not participate in the 
determination of the result.
```

Same does not work for collection valued attributes (one-to-many, many-to-many), because it is not possible to navigate to their attributes via path expressions.

Comment: That is a very precise answer, thanks ! To extend the subject to collections, could you illustrate what happens with a collection attribute ?